# AJAX routing Error for Delete. Why do I have a DELETE routing error for the index page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am very close to completing an AJAX delete method but I am confused about an error message that I receive when the AJAX method is completed. Here is the output generated from my terminal when I click on the AJAX method:

```
started DELETE "/tasks/71" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-02 22:38:03 -0400
Processing by TasksController#destroy as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"71"}
Task Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1     
[["id", 71]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1  [["id", 71]]
(75.5ms)  COMMIT

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 82ms (ActiveRecord: 76.5ms)


Started DELETE "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-02 22:38:03 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/"):
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

Notice the Started DELETE '/' for 127.0  etc. part. What exactly is that telling me? From the output, I see that the AJAX function was completed succesfully. I'm confused as to what the Routing Error is referring to. Can someone explain to me what this is so I may be able to fix it?

Also, this is my controller code for the destroy function.

```
def destroy
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
@task.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!"}
  format.json { render root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!" }
end
```

end

As you can see, the code should be correct. I've tried changing render to redirect_to but I still get the same problem. Thse are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'tasks#index'
resources :tasks, except: [:show]
```

Finally, this is my ajax.js.erb file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(this).on('delete', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var data_info = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: Routes.task_path(id),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data_info,
    success: function(response) {
      $(response).remove();
    },
  });
  });
});
```

Where could the problem be? I don't think its in my ajax.js.erb file because the action completes. If not there then where? Thanks for the help in advance.

-----------EDIT-----------

I just realized that my output used the JS format not JSON to delete an item. Now I have a follow up question as to why that is? I'm even more confused because in the ajax call I specifically specify it as a JSON call not JS. Did I do something wrong?

-----------EDIT-------------

I tried inserting this line of code as recommended by Rick Peck.

```
format.js { render root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!", layout: !request.xhr? }
```

but now I am receiving a 500 internal server error:

```
started DELETE "/tasks/108" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-03 14:47:36 -0400
Processing by TasksController#destroy as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"108"}
Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 108]]
 (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = $1  [["id", 108]]
 (1.8ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass:
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:178:in `normalize_name'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:153:in `args_for_lookup'
```

What makes this extremely annoying is that I'm unable to use debugger to checkout out what's happening. I've deduced that something is happening in my ajax code. Right here:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'DELETE',
  url: Routes.task_path(id),
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data_info,
  success: function(response) {
    $(response).remove();
    // Something is wrong here with the remove function undefined method 'empty'.
    // Why is the call being sent as JS not JSON
    // Where is the 500 error coming from?
  },
});
});
```

I suspect that my response does not contain the information that I want. All I want to do is remove that HTML element that contained my task entry. I can't see what it is though because I can't use debugger. I can't tell if its my ajax logic in the controller or the ajax.js.erb file. Any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is that there is some javascript making a `DELETE` request to `/` or it is a problem with the `link_to` you have on the page for the delete action. Run `rake routes` in your project and make sure everything looks ok. I'd remove the html support in your `respond_to` block if you're only using the JSON handler.

Comment: @Andy Atkinson, thanks for the reply. I've checked out my routes and everything seems to be fine. Could you elaborate on the problem with the link_to button? What exactly do you think could be the problem? I'm really at a loss. I don't get why my destroy action is being sent as JS when I clearly want json in the ajax.js.erb file.

Comment: What is this: `url: Routes.task_path(id)`? Where is `Routes.task_path` defined?

Comment: Routes.task_path(id) comes from a ruby gem that i use for javascript. It comes from j-routes gem.

Answer (score 0):

```
format.json { render root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!" }
```

Why are you rendering the `root_path` with `json`? This will be the "root" of your problem - as JSON will just want to return a plain old data object to the browser

---

**JSON**

I would highly **recommend removing the `render` part of the `json` response**. You don't need it - if you want to render HTML as a response, you should use the `js` format:

```
respond_to do |format|
   format.json { render json: "Task Successfully Removed, Good Job!".to_json }
   format.js   { render root_path, notice: "Task Successfully Removed, Good job!", layout: !request.xhr? }
end
```

If you look up the [Wikipedia definition of JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you'll find this:

> JavaScript Object Notation, is an open standard format that uses
>   human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of
>   attribute–value pairs. It is used primarily to transmit data between a
>   server and web application, as an alternative to XML.

This means if you're trying to render HTML with JSON, it goes against convention & will cause problems down the line

--

In terms of why you're sending a `JS` request, rather than `json`, I've found Rails to call the JSON mime-type "JS" before today. Although I don't have any references, I *think* your usage of `json` should be okay, if you get the `render` method sorted out (as above)

Comment: Hey @Rich Peck thanks for the reply. I tried implementing your code but I seem to be getting a 500 internal server error now. I'm going to make an edit and if you had some time do you think you could take a quick look. I really am stumped and this is really starting to bother me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the redirect you do in your destroy action. When you use an xhr (ajax) requests other than GET or POST, your browser uses that same request method (i.e. DELETE in your case) for the next request.

You can fix this by passing in a status of 303 like so:

```
redirect_to root_path, status: 303
```